# python uwsgi not loading changes

Tags: python, uwsgi

i am using uwsgi to serve python application. app was using a particular vrsion of `falcon python` now i upgraded the package by removing it and reinstalling it. but the change is not reflected by the uwsgi server it is still using the older code even when i restart `uwsgi`. why is this problem coming? i can see older version of code which was generating error in the `uwsgi logs`

Answer (score 1):

You must restart uWSGI after code changes.

If you are using a virtual-environment:

- Ensure that you haven't installed `falcon` globally (`deactivate` first)
- Make sure that you've activated the right one, you can use `echo $PATH` and `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` to check sanity.

If it *still* reads the older version, use `pip freeze` or `pip list` to debug your environment. Make sure you have totally uninstalled the older version.

As last resort, delete your virtual-environment and re-create it. If you're not using virtual-environments with Python, start using them.